# What does 0x80020101 represent?

Tags: windows

A simple question that I can't find an answer for in Microsoft's error lookup or easily using google: what does the HRESULT 0x80020101 represent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247784

> The HRESULT 0x80020101 translates to SCRIPT_E_REPORTED. This error can be observed when a scripting component fails under MTS.

Comment: In an inevitable case of coincidence, I found that myself about 30 seconds after posting the question.  Good to have it documented somewhere easier to find though.

Comment: It happens :) glad you found it.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Eric Lippert in this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/22/53267.aspx):

> `SCRIPT_E_REPORTED`   `0x80020101` -- the script engines return this
>   to the host when there has been an unhandled error that the host has
>   already been informed about via OnScriptError.