# How to use code to click a button in BluePrism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I want to click a button in a web page with BluePrism, as if I was using the Navigation stage, but I want to do it with code, preferably C#. I am struggling to find documentation of what actions are exposed to the Code stage.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on *why* you want to do this? A code stage is just an arbitrary block of Visual Basic or C# code - if you have the proper DLLs loaded up you could hypothetically complete any task at all.

Comment: I have some logic in code and I want to perform some task (clicking) from the Navigation stage in some cases, instead of mapping a complex constellation of stages. I am asking if actions that are available in Navigation stage, and buttons spied through the application modeller, are exposed through some C# API or otherwise available in the Code stage.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not really the way Blue Prism is designed to handle such interactions. There may be some undocumented APIs you could try to hook into, but ultimately Blue Prism is designed to be used by business users & developers alike, and thus centers its functionality around its flowchart-esque interface. If you require something ultra complex, you might as well leverage some sort of scripting to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In case this serves as a workaround, you can also inject and invoke Javascript using Blue Prism to set values, click buttons, etc..  Some details to get started here:

[Unable to Invoke Inserted Javascript Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537198/unable-to-invoke-inserted-javascript-fragment)